# Dynamically assign method / Method as variable

Tags: c#, methods

So i have 2 classes named A and B.

A has a method "public void Foo()".

B has several other methods.

What i need is a variable in class B, that will be assigned the Foo() method of class A.
This variable should afterwards be "executed" (=> so it should execute the assigned method of class A).

How to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reed gave you the right answer.  It's also worth pointing out that you can use other delegate signatures besides Action.

There are generic versions like `Action<T>` (one arg), `Action<T1, T2>` (two args), etc...
Also if your method has a return type, check out `Func<T, TResult>`.

- Action docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx
- Func docs:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Or of course you can define your own delegate type.

Answer (score 60):

It sounds like you want to use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) here.

Basically, you can add, in class "B":

```
class B
{
    public Action TheMethod { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public static void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Foo"); }
    public static void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Bar"); }
}
```

You could then set:

```
B b = new B();

b.TheMethod = A.Foo; // Assign the delegate
b.TheMethod(); // Invoke the delegate...

b.TheMethod = A.Bar;
b.TheMethod(); // Invoke the delegate...
```

This would print out "Foo" then "Bar".

Comment: thx a lot this is working. i was missing the "Action" keyword :)

Comment: @nr1: There are actually many options there - `Action` will allow you to use a method that doesn't return a value and takes no parameters.  You can use `Func<int,string>` if your methods all take an int and return a string, for example.