# C# Method as variable

Tags: c#, variables, selenium-webdriver

I have test code in C# Visual Studio with Selenium. I have there few test class and one Utility class.

```
using ...
namespace Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //CODE
    }
    [TestClass]
    public void Test2()
    {
        //CODE
    }
    [TestClass]
    public void Test3()
    {
        //CODE
    }
    [TestClass]
    public void Utility()
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        int a,b,c;
        string name, password;
        srting[] info = {"a","b","c"};
        //other variables
    }
}
```

My question is simply (there was few similar questions but they won't work for me like decaration in [Dynamically assign method / Method as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367152/c-dynamically-assign-method-method-as-variable)). Is there possible to create method from my variables in class Utility to use them in other classes as variable without coppying them all the time? Or there is other thing i can do for that?

Thx for help
Janer

Comment: You can create a `static` methods and you can reuse the same

Comment: U mean 'public static void Utility' and the use or that method with variables need to be 'public static'?

Comment: The method with variables need to be 'public static'...this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution favored by the Gang of Four is "Favor composition over inheritance" which takes this:

```
[TestClass]
public void Test3()
{
    //CODE
}
[TestClass]
public void Utility()
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    int a,b,c;
    string name, password;
    srting[] info = {"a","b","c"};
    //other variables
}
```

And converts it to this:

```
[TestClass]
public void Test3()
{
    var utility = new Utility();
    //do the test
}
```

The new utility class would look like this:

```
 public class Utility()
 {
    IWebDriver driver {get;set;}
    int a {get;set; int b {get;set;} int c {get;set;};
    string name {get;set;} string password {get;set;}
    string[] info {get{return new string[]{"a","b","c"}};
    //other variables
 }
```

Comment: and then just refer to them by `utility.driver` and so on??

Comment: Yes exactly... the tests now "contain" the utilities.  The theory get's deeper but that's enough for now.