# How to and should I store a frequently called method in a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

In Lua, it is slightly faster to put a function you call often from a global math library. For example:

```
local variable = math.sin
```

Instead of `math.sin(x)`, you would now use it as `variable(x)` (bad naming used for demonstration purposes).

Well, what about C#? Imagine you want to call method `Class.method()` one million times. I assume it would be faster to put that method inside a variable, but how would I do that?

In my case, I am calling function `Mathf.PerlinNoise` thousands of times relatively frequently and I would like to put it inside a variable.

How do I do that and should I even bother? How much can this affect performance in extreme cases (tens of millions of calls for example)?

Comment: Don't assume, know. In this case, measure performance. Go find an example using BenchmarkDotNet and use it to measure performance with and without that variable. In .NET this is called a Delegate, you can find many examples on the internet. I can tell you the outcome though, the static method call is going to be fastest, not by a huge margin, but still fastest. But don't take my word for it, learn how to measure things like this, it's a skill that is good to have.

Comment: Methods can be stored as delegates.  I would strongly suggest not putting methods in variables when you can already access it from where it's supposed to be.  If you need to select from a list of possible methods to use, you can put a bunch of delegates into a dictionary and execute one or the other.  I'm not particularly aware of any performance difference, but I figure it won't be much and this seems like it will increase the confusion and complexity of your project unnecessarily.

Comment: Looks like `Mathf.PerlinNoise` has a signature of `(float -> float -> float)`, so `Func<float,float,float> perlinNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise;` should get you an anonymous delegate to the function. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367152/dynamically-assign-method-method-as-variable.  The suggested duplicate doesn't speak to performance/optimization at all.

Comment: In Lua what you are really doing is _G['math']['sin'](x).  This requires a lookup in the __index metamethod on _G for 'math' that returns a table, then another on that table that returns the function then the function call.   In C# the compiler just uses the address of the function directly, there is no meta method type lookup for statics like this, so storing it in a local variable wont make a difference.